# How to scan for, create, read and write text files in python?

Tags: python

I've been messing around with a collatz program I wrote a couple of days back to learn python, recently incorporating a list.

```
from heapq import nlargest

list=[]

number = input("Please enter range: ")+1


def collatz(a):
    if a%2==0:
        return a/2
    else:
        return (3*a)+1


for x in range(1,number):
    n=x
    count=(-1)
    while n>=1:
        print "%s " % (n),

        if n==1:
            n=0

        n=collatz(n)
        count+=1
    print "\n\n%s: %s\n\n" % (x, count)
    list.insert(x,count)
    x+=1

print "%s\n\n" % (list)
```

Now I want to be able to save the data output so that I can use it in excel for example, but also so that I don't have to keep starting from 1 (say I run it once up to 10, and then run it again, I want it to start from 10 up to 20 instead, just like if I ran it once up to 20).  If possible, I'd also like it to generate its own text file if none is found.
Cheers.

Comment: [7.2 Reading and writing files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) might be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is append your data to a CSV:

```
import csv
filename = "myfilename.csv"

with open(filename, 'a') as myfile:
    writer = csv.writer(myfile)
    writer.writerow(list)
```

the `'a'` means append.  It creates a new file if none is found.  `'w'` writes a file and overwrites it if you run the program again.
Use `writerow` to write a single list (single row), use `writerows` to write a list of lists (all rows)

Then you can later read your csv again:

```
import csv
with open(filename, 'r') as myfile:
    reader = csv.reader(myfile)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

Comment: Cheers, I feel like I should learn a bit about this.  Where can I learn about it?  Is there somewhere online that goes over the basics of csv files?  Thanks for the help btw

Comment: All of the basic python tools are very easily googlable.  "python csv" yields this nice article:  https://pymotw.com/2/csv/

Answer (score 0):

You could create a data frame which you then could write to a new .csv file

```
import pandas as pd
```

Creating a [DataFrame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html), at the end of your code: `df = pd.DataFrame(data=*some data e.g. list*, index=i)`

```
i = range(1, x)

df = pd.DataFrame(data=list, index=i)
print 'dataframe:  ', df
```

From data frame to .csv file: [DataFrame.to_csv()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

```
df.to_csv('C:/Users/.../new_file.csv')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, do you know where I could learn a bit more about this?  It looks really alien to me right now...

Comment: You can click on the blue text in my answer which takes you to these links: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html and http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

Comment: @user7389469 Considering that you are super new, I'd recommend sticking to built-in functions.  While I really like pandas, installing extra packages adds an extra layer of complexity to your learning curve that you really don't need for writing CSVs.